# Angular 2 - How to choose what represents a component and child component in a page?

Tags: angular, components

Starting a Project using Angular2, I wanted to know if any of you knows how to distinguish components and sub component. How are we supposed to settle on the following architecture's decisions :

1. When does an element should be represented by a component ? when start using subcomponent ?
2. When to choose to communicate via services between components ? when to choose Input and Output directives ?
3. what should be considered a module rather than a component ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of a vague question, because there's no golden rule for everything.

> 1. When does an element should be represented by a component ? when start using subcomponent ?

What is a component? If we look at the dictionary: ***a part or element of a larger whole*** The idea of components in Angular is that they encapsulate all the logic, allowing you to reuse them across your application. Rule of thumb T-DRY (Try to be DRY), don't repeat yourself, if you keep using the same logic on several components, maybe you could extract that into a single component and re-use that component instead.  Also it's a nice way to reduce your html markup, for example looking at stack overflow we could have the answer/question component, the markup is the same for both. But in this component we would probably would have some child components, like the voting component, the profile component, the tags component.

> 2. When to choose to communicate via services between components ? when
>      to choose Input and Output directives ?

This one is simple, you only use **Inputs** and **Outputs** when your component it's only used as a **direct child** and the parent is the one responsible for **providing** the logic or data. Why? If you have a route that **points directly** to your component, you can't have inputs and outputs. Another reason is if your component is a deep nested  grand grandchild, you don't want to keep passing your **outputs**/**inputs** through your components, that's too cumbersome.

> 3. what should be considered a module rather than a component ?

I advise you too read the official [Angular 2 style guide](https://angular.io/styleguide), there's the section [app structure & modules](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#app-structure-and-angular-modules) basically the idea is to create modules per features, or in case you have a simple app per url. Here's a quote from that section:

> Do create an Angular module for all distinct features in an
>   application (e.g. Heroes feature).
>
> Do place the feature module in the same named folder as the feature
>   area (.e.g app/heroes).
>
> Do name the feature module file reflecting the name of the feature
>   area and folder (e.g. app/heroes/heroes.module.ts)
>
> Do name the feature module symbol reflecting the name of the feature
>   area, folder, and file (e.g. app/heroes/heroes.module.ts defines
>   HeroesModule)
>
> Why? A feature module can expose or hide its implementation from other
>   modules.
>
> Why? A feature module identifies distinct sets of related components
>   that comprise the feature area.
>
> Why? A feature module can easily be routed to both eagerly and lazily.
>
> Why? A feature module defines clear boundaries between specific
>   functionality and other application features.
>
> Why? A feature module helps clarify and make it easier to assign
>   development responsibilities to different teams.
>
> Why? A feature module can easily be isolated for testing.

Answer (score 3):

1. When you start repeating your code, it's time to use a component. A good example is the 'button' or 'input' html tags they support multiple features such as enable/disabled, read-only, validation etc. If you had to code them each time it would be really annoying, then you should code them once as components and simply write their html tag instead of coding them again.
   Also when something gets too complicated I like to make it a component, It can be easier to manage your code.
2. If you are communicating inside a component and never outside of it, you should probably use the Input/Output decorators, otherwise, if you want to communicate with non persistent components or components which are all over your app, you should probably use services. By non persistent I mean if you want to communicate with components generated on the fly, you should use the services.
3. I'm new to modules so I don't want to spread false information so I won't say anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

1. When it does something you can't otherwise do with html/css; or when you want to encapsulate common functionality or appearance.
2. I found it best to use services in "smart" components. They have very little template code, usually just enough to delegate data to subcomponents - "dumb" components. Subcomponents, on the other hand, have a lot of template code but very little js/ts code - just enough to define Input/Output properties.
3. When you have a common functionality that you would re-use in other projects, it's probably a good idea to make that a separate module. For example, a login form with its logic, template, styling, services, pipes...

Comment: 3rd point makes sense to me
for the second point, you never used services to communicate between parent and child components ? always input/ouput ?

Comment: I wouldn't say never, but I usually use ngrx/store to keep app data and distribute the data when/where needed - from store, through parent components, to subcomponents that display it...

Comment: very interesting ! never used ngrx/store